# ¿Cómo acceder a unidad compartida (pide user y pass) desde Linux con Python?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Necesito poder usar los archivos de música que tengo dentro de un directorio en una unidad de red compartida, (obviamente protegida por usuario y contraseña, es un NAS), desde Linux (concretamente Ubuntu) y con Python.

Tengo ya funciones para acceder a una carpeta con música dentro del propio *Ubuntu*, pero no consigo encontrar cómo acceder a la del NAS, pese a que sí accedo gráficamente al NAS y sus archivos, pasar como parámetro la ruta remota no funciona.

Estoy un poco perdido con esto ¿alguien puede arrojar un poco de luz al asunto? Muchas gracias de antemano.

Esto es lo que tengo que funciona pero sólo localmente.

```
#Listar y numerar contenido directorio pasando ruta como parámetro.
#Primero muestra directorios y después archivos.
def listar_contenido(path):
    from os import scandir
    CONTENIDO_DIR = (obj.name for obj in scandir(path) if obj.is_dir())
    CONTENIDO_FILE = (obj.name for obj in scandir(path) if obj.is_file())
    contador = 0
    for element in CONTENIDO_DIR:
        print(contador, element)
        contador += 1
    for element in CONTENIDO_FILE:
        print(contador, element)
        contador += 1
#Directorio a listar.
path= "/ruta/local/directorio"

listar_contenido(path)
```

Comment: Hola Daniel ¿qué protocolo usas para los archivos compartidos? ¿NFS, SAMBA?

Comment: Hola FJSevilla, de forma gráfica uso SAMBA, es decir abro un explorador de archivos, introduzco smb://IP o Nombre de mi nas/directorio compartido. en ese punto salta una ventana pidiendo usuario y contraseña. He probado incluso dejando esto ya guardado para que el sistema lo recuerde pero sigue sin funcionar. imagino que seguramente sea porque son usuarios distintos los que tratan de acceder al nas, pero no sé como solucionarlo. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel:

¿Has intentado utilizar algún módulo de Python como PySmbClient o pysmb?

https://pypi.org/project/PySmbClient/ o https://pypi.org/project/pysmb/1.1.19/

Ambos módulos poseen en los métodos para establecer la conexión con argumentos para indicar las credenciales.

En el siguiente ejemplo, he usado el módulo pysmb, el cuál puedes instalar con `pip3 install pysmb`

He usado de prueba el siguiente docker https://hub.docker.com/r/sixeyed/samba/ para no tener que montar el escenario en un equipo real.

Añadí un usuario de prueba

```
adduser usuarioprueba
smbpasswd -a usuarioprueba
```

Añadí el usuario creado a la configuración de smb:

```
[music]
   path = /mnt/audio/music
   browsable = yes
   read only = no
   guest ok = yes
   valid users = usuarioprueba
```

Y añadí 3 ficheros de prueba:

```
root@samba:/# ls -laht /mnt/audio/music/
total 8.0K
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4.0K Jun  9 16:44 .
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jun  9 16:44 fichero_ejemplo_3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jun  9 16:44 fichero_ejemplo_2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jun  9 16:44 fichero_ejemplo_1
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jun  9 16:43 ..
root@samba:/#
```

En el host, he usado el siguiente script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection

usuario = 'usuarioprueba'
password = 'abc123.'
server = 'localhost'

conexion = SMBConnection(usuario, password, server, server)
conexion.connect(server)

shares = conexion.listShares()

for share in shares:
    if not share.isSpecial and share.name not in ['NETLOGON', 'SYSVOL']:
        sharedfiles = conexion.listPath(share.name, '/')
        for sharedfile in sharedfiles:
            print(sharedfile)
```

Y el resultado de ejecutar el script, el listado:

```
$ -> python3 pysmb.py 
.
..
fichero_ejemplo_1
fichero_ejemplo_3
fichero_ejemplo_2
```

Podrías adentrarte un poco más con la documentación pero se hace extensa.
Al estar en ubuntu y poder utilizar el comando smbclient, también podrías utilizar el módulo subprocess. De esta forma podrás ejecutar los mismos comandos que ejecutas por interfaz de línea de comandos:

```
smbclient //172.17.0.2/music -U usuarioprueba -c "dir"
Enter WORKGROUP\usuarioprueba's password: 
  .                                   D        0  Tue Jun  9 18:44:25 2020
  ..                                  D        0  Tue Jun  9 18:43:47 2020
  fichero_ejemplo_1                   N        0  Tue Jun  9 18:44:22 2020
  fichero_ejemplo_3                   N        0  Tue Jun  9 18:44:25 2020
  fichero_ejemplo_2                   N        0  Tue Jun  9 18:44:24 2020
```